# Is there a way to auto connect Sphero in android

Tags: android, sphero-api, sphero

I want my app to connect all paired Sphero automatically.
I saw there is a class called `orbotix.robot.internal.AutoReconnectCommand;`
but I cannot find any javadoc for this class.
Is there a way to auto connect Sphero in android without showing the connection screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer for my own question 
You can use :

```
porvider.addConnectionListener(mConnectionListener);
porvider.addDiscoveryListener(mDiscoveryListener);
```

For connecting Sphero without using the given GUI from orbotix
in the mDiscoverListener you will need to implement a method call `onFound`.
In case you have only one robot you can implement it in the following way

```
@Override
        public void onFound(List<Sphero> paramList)
        {
            Sphero s=paramList.get(0);
            RobotProvider.getDefaultProvider().connect(s);
        }
```

If you have more than one robot you can add GUI by yourself for choosing a Sphero